# How to add a space before the text in a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have created a JLabel and what to put some text in it. But when i look at the result, the text to close to the edge of the screen. So i want to add a space "  " before it so that it moves further away from the edge of the screen. But this does not work, the space does not get added no matter how many spaces i put before the text.

```
JLabel nameLabel= new JLabel("Name");
nameLabel.setText("   Hello my name is tom.");
add(nameLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

As you can see above, i have tried to add a space before the hello to make it move further away from the edge of the screen. But the space just doesnt show up when i run the program.

I know i can move the label a bit right, but i am only supposed to you this layout. I just want to find out if there is away to add a space before the text that shows up when the program is run.

Comment: You could consider using an `EmptyBorder`

Comment: If borders aren't your style you maybe able to put an '&nbsp' in HTML tags as the text, but I haven't tried it..... I just know that some HTML tags are supported by labels.

Comment: @MarkW thanks alot, this worked! If you put your answer in the answer section I could accept the answer.

Comment: For the record, MadProgrammers solution, or one using BoxLayout struts, or any other fixed sized invisible component IS a better solution... but Im glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider using an `EmptyBorder`, for example...

```
JLabel nameLabel= new JLabel("Name");
nameLabel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 20, 0, 0));
nameLabel.setText("Hello my name is tom.");
add(nameLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Have a look at [How to Use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more details